# How to use C++ classes with ctypes?

Tags: c++, python, ctypes

I'm just getting started with ctypes and would like to use a C++ class that I have exported in a dll file from within python using ctypes.
So lets say my C++ code looks something like this:

```c++
class MyClass {
  public:
    int test();
...
```

I would know create a .dll file that contains this class and then load the .dll file in python using ctypes.
Now how would I create an Object of type MyClass and call its test function? Is that even possible with ctypes? Alternatively I would consider using SWIG or Boost.Python but ctypes seems like the easiest option for small projects.

Answer (score 49, accepted):

The short story is that there is no standard binary interface for C++ in the way that there is for C.  Different compilers output different binaries for the same C++ dynamic libraries, due to name mangling and different ways to handle the stack between library function calls.

So, unfortunately, there really isn't a portable way to access C++ libraries *in general*.  But, for one compiler at a time, it's no problem.

[This blog post](http://blog.vrplumber.com/index.php?/archives/197-Ctypes-for-C++-is-going-to-be-a-pain-due-to-politics-Bothering-language-creators-is-fun....html) also has a short overview of why this currently won't work.  Maybe after C++0x comes out, we'll have a standard ABI for C++?  Until then, you're probably not going to have any way to access C++ classes through Python's `ctypes`.

Answer (score 65):

Besides Boost.Python(which is probably a more friendly solution for larger projects that require one-to-one mapping of C++ classes to python classes), you could provide on the C++ side a C interface. It's one solution of many so it has its own trade offs, but I will present it for the benefit of those who aren't familiar with the technique. For full disclosure, with this approach one wouldn't be interfacing C++ to python, but C++ to C to Python. Below I included an example that meets your requirements to show you the general idea of the extern "c" facility of C++ compilers.

```
//YourFile.cpp (compiled into a .dll or .so file)
#include <new> //For std::nothrow
//Either include a header defining your class, or define it here. 

extern "C"  //Tells the compile to use C-linkage for the next scope.
{
    //Note: The interface this linkage region needs to use C only.  
    void * CreateInstanceOfClass( void )
    {
        // Note: Inside the function body, I can use C++. 
        return new(std::nothrow) MyClass;
    }

    //Thanks Chris. 
    void DeleteInstanceOfClass (void *ptr)
    {
         delete(std::nothrow) ptr; 
    }

    int CallMemberTest(void *ptr)
    {

        // Note: A downside here is the lack of type safety. 
        // You could always internally(in the C++ library) save a reference to all 
        // pointers created of type MyClass and verify it is an element in that
        //structure. 
        //
        // Per comments with Andre, we should avoid throwing exceptions.  
        try
        {
            MyClass * ref = reinterpret_cast<MyClass *>(ptr);
            return ref->Test();
        }
        catch(...)
        {
           return -1; //assuming -1 is an error condition. 
        }
    }

} //End C linkage scope.
```

You can compile this code with

```
gcc -shared -o test.so test.cpp
#creates test.so in your current working directory.
```

In your python code you could do something like this (interactive prompt from 2.7 shown):

```
>>> from ctypes import cdll
>>> stdc=cdll.LoadLibrary("libc.so.6") # or similar to load c library
>>> stdcpp=cdll.LoadLibrary("libstdc++.so.6") # or similar to load c++ library
>>> myLib=cdll.LoadLibrary("/path/to/test.so")
>>> spam = myLib.CreateInstanceOfClass()
>>> spam
[outputs the pointer address of the element]
>>> value=CallMemberTest(spam)
[does whatever Test does to the spam reference of the object]
```

I'm sure Boost.Python does something similar under the hood, but perhaps understanding the lower levels concepts is helpful. I would be more excited about this method if you were attempting to access functionality of a C++ library and a one-to-one mapping was not required.

For more information on C/C++ interaction check out this page from Sun: http://dsc.sun.com/solaris/articles/mixing.html#cpp_from_c

Comment: Indeed, this is a little tedious, but it works.  You'll specifically want to watch out for exceptions though.  I don't think it's safe to assume the `ctypes` module handles C functions that throw exceptions very well.  In particular, the `return new MyClass;` statement is very dangerous since it can raise `std::bad_alloc`.

Comment: Please do add a `DestroyInstanceOfClass()` function as well.

Comment: That's a very good point. I will edit the example to use no throw variant. One other trick would be to catch all exceptions in a try block in the C++ body of the function.

Comment: Please consider Gabriel Devillers answer below, fixing memory issues with 64 bits libraries.

Comment: `delete(std::nothrow) ptr; ` fails to compile for me, You should repalce it with `delete ptr;`

Comment: Not working either, until I added the function signature as in https://www.auctoris.co.uk/2017/04/29/calling-c-classes-from-python-with-ctypes/

Answer (score 20):

The [answer by AudaAero](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7061012/4669135) is very good but not complete (at least for me).

On my system (Debian Stretch x64 with GCC and G++ 6.3.0, Python 3.5.3) I have segfaults as soon has I call a member function that *access a member value* of the class.
I diagnosticated by printing pointer values to stdout that the void* pointer coded on 64 bits in wrappers is being represented on 32 bits in Python. Thus big problems occurs when it is passed back to a member function wrapper.

The solution I found is to change:

```
spam = myLib.CreateInstanceOfClass()
```

Into

```
Class_ctor_wrapper = myLib.CreateInstanceOfClass
Class_ctor_wrapper.restype = c_void_p
spam = c_void_p(Class_ctor_wrapper())
```

So two things were missing: setting the return type to c_void_p (the default is int) **and** then creating a c_void_p object (not just an integer).

I wish I could have written a comment but I still lack 27 rep points.

Answer (score 4):

Extending [AudaAero's](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7061012/7063567) and [Gabriel Devillers](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42609781/7063567) answer I would complete the class object instance creation by:
`stdc=c_void_p(cdll.LoadLibrary("libc.so.6"))`
using `ctypes` `c_void_p` data type ensures the proper representation of the class object pointer within python.

Also make sure that the dll's memory management be handled by the dll (allocated memory in the dll should be deallocated also in the dll, and not in python)!

Answer (score 3):

I ran into the same problem. From trial and error and some internet research (not necessarily from knowing the g++ compiler or C++ very well), I came across this particular solution that seems to be working quite well for me.

```cpp
//model.hpp
class Model{
public:
    static Model* CreateModel(char* model_name) asm("CreateModel"); // static method, creates an instance of the class
    double GetValue(uint32_t index) asm("GetValue"); // object method
}
```

```py
#model.py
from ctypes import ...
if __name__ == '__main__':
    # load dll as model_dll

    # Static Method Signature
    fCreateModel = getattr(model_dll, 'CreateModel') # or model_dll.CreateModel
    fCreateModel.argtypes = [c_char_p]
    fCreateModel.restype = c_void_p

   # Object Method Signature
    fGetValue = getattr(model_dll, 'GetValue') # or model_dll.GetValue
    fGetValue.argtypes = [c_void_p, c_uint32] # Notice two Params
    fGetValue.restype = c_double


    # Calling the Methods
    obj_ptr = fCreateModel(c_char_p(b"new_model"))
    val = fGetValue(obj_ptr, c_int32(0)) # pass in obj_ptr as first param of obj method
```

```
>>> nm -Dg libmodel.so 
                 U cbrt@GLIBC_2.2.5
                 U close@GLIBC_2.2.5
00000000000033a0 T CreateModel # <----- Static Method
                 U __cxa_atexit@GLIBC_2.2.5
                 w __cxa_finalize@GLIBC_2.2.5
                 U fprintf@GLIBC_2.2.5
0000000000002b40 T GetValue # <----- Object Method
                 w __gmon_start__
...
...
... # Mangled Symbol Names Below
0000000000002430 T _ZN12SHMEMWrapper4HashEPKc
0000000000006120 B _ZN12SHMEMWrapper8info_mapE
00000000000033f0 T _ZN5Model12DestroyModelEPKc
0000000000002b20 T _ZN5Model14GetLinearIndexElll
```

First, I was able to avoid the `extern "C"` directive completely by instead using the `asm` keyword which, to my knowledge, asks the compiler to use a given name instead of the generated one when exporting the function to the shared object lib's symbol table. This allowed me to avoid the weird symbol names that the C++ compiler generates automatically. They look something like the `_ZN1...` pattern you see above. Then in a program using Python ctypes, I was able to access the class functions directly using the custom name I gave them. The program looks like `fhandle = mydll.myfunc` or `fhandler = getattr(mydll, 'myfunc')` instead of `fhandle  = getattr(mydll, '_ZN12...myfunc...')`. Of course, you could just use the long name; it would make no difference, but I figure the shorter name is a little cleaner and doesn't require using `nm` to read the symbol table and extract the names in the first place.

Second, in the spirit of Python's style of object oriented programming, I decided to try passing in my class' object pointer as the first argument of the class object method, just like when we pass `self` in as the first method in Python object methods. To my surprise, it worked! See the Python section above. Apparently, if you set the first argument in the `fhandle.argtypes` argument to `c_void_ptr` and pass in the ptr you get from your class' static factory method, the program should execute cleanly. Class static methods seem to work as one would expect like in Python; just use the original function signature.

I'm using g++ 12.1.1, python 3.10.5 on Arch Linux. I hope this helps someone.

Comment: This seems to work quite well. But it fails the criteria to be able to reuse any C++ library that you cannot contribute to.