# ctypes: Initialize array of arrays and pass to C function

Tags: c++, python, ctypes

I've been fooling with ctypes and have come across two problems:

**Problem 1.** I would like to build a `cellComplex` using `double*` arrays, but I want `new_cellComplex` to accept an array of `double*`'s (along with a `size_t` argument) rather than a fixed number of `double*`'s.  With a fixed number the code looks like this **(and it runs fine)**:

```c++
extern "C" {
  void * new_cellComplex(double* p_x, double* p_y, double* p_z) {

    std::vector< std::pair<double,double> > point;
    point.push_back( std::make_pair(p_x[0],p_x[1])); 
    point.push_back( std::make_pair(p_x[0],p_x[1])); 
    point.push_back( std::make_pair(p_x[0],p_x[1])); 

    cellComplex<double>* cmplx = new cellComplex<double>(point);
    return cmplx;
  }
```

with Python code:

```py
import ctypes

cellComplex_lib = ctypes.cdll.LoadLibrary('./cellComplex_lib.so')
cellComplex_lib.new_cellComplex.restype  = ctypes.c_void_p
cellComplex_lib.new_cellComplex.argtypes = [ctypes.c_double*2,
                                            ctypes.c_double*2,
                                            ctypes.c_double*2]

p_x = (ctypes.c_double*2)(0.0,1.0)
p_y = (ctypes.c_double*2)(0.0,1.0)
p_z = (ctypes.c_double*2)(0.0,1.0)

cmplx = cellComplex_lib.new_cellComplex(p_x,p_y,p_z)
```

I would rather have the following **(which segfaults)**:

```c++
extern "C" {
  void * new_cellComplex(double** p, size_t dim) {

    std::vector< std::pair<double,double> > point;
    for (size_t i=0; i<dim; ++i) {
      point.push_back( std::make_pair(p[i][0],p[i][1])); 
    } 
    cellComplex<double>* cmplx = new cellComplex<double>(point);
    return cmplx;
  }
}
```

With Python code:

```py
import ctypes

dim = 3
cellComplex_lib = ctypes.cdll.LoadLibrary('./cellComplex_lib.so')
cellComplex_lib.new_cellComplex.restype  = ctypes.c_void_p
cellComplex_lib.new_cellComplex.argtypes = [(ctypes.c_double*2)*dim,
                                            ctypes.c_size_t]

p_x = (ctypes.c_double*2)(0.0,1.0)
p_y = (ctypes.c_double*2)(0.0,1.0)
p_z = (ctypes.c_double*2)(0.0,1.0)

p = ((ctypes.c_double*2)*dim)(p_x,p_y,p_z)

cmplx = cellComplex_lib.new_cellComplex(p,dim)
```

^This doesn't work and I don't know why.

**Problem 2.** (Included here because it's *glaring* in **Problem 1**) I am returning an essentially anonymous pointer from my `C` code!  This just feels, well, dirty, and there must be a better way to return a custom data type and deal with it back in Python.  For the record, I am *extremely* grateful for [this stackoverflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7061012/390433) where I learned such sorcery - but I'm not going to be able to sleep at night as long as it's in my code...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of `double **`, use `double [][2]`. You're passing a contiguous C array that you want to access as a pointer to a row of 2 items. The first index is the row index.

Declaring the array as a `double **` is a pointer to a `double` pointer, so `p[i]` is a pointer, and `p[i][0]` dereferences it again. But `p[i]` is a `NULL` pointer by chance according to your data.

> Refer to the comp.lang.c FAQ, [question
>   6.18](http://c-faq.com/aryptr/pass2dary.html): My compiler complained when I passed a two-dimensional array to a function expecting a
>   pointer to a pointer.

For the return type, you can subclass `c_void_p`, or use the hooks `from_param` and `_as_parameter_` per the last paragraph of [section 15.17.1.7](http://docs.python.org/2/library/ctypes#specifying-the-required-argument-types-function-prototypes) in the ctypes docs.