# Python ctypes pointers dealing with DLL exported class

Tags: python, c++, pointers, dll, ctypes

I'm trying to export a Class within a DLL and use it in Python. So lets say my class is called **MyClass**, and to use it I need to make an instance with a method called **getupdate()** which looks like this :

```
MyClass*    MyClass::getupdate()
{
    if(update==NULL)                    
    {
        update  =   new MyClass();  
    }           
    return update;
}
```

So after compiling the dll, I load it in a Python script using ctypes module, like this :

```
from ctypes import *

win = WinDLL('MyDLL')
```

And here I don't know how to create an instance of MyClass like we can do simply in C++ :

```
MyClass* update;
update  =   MyClass::getupdate();
```

I need to have a pointer to MyClass in Python and access the rest of methods within this pointer.

Thank you in advance for you help.

Comment: It's ctypes, not cpptypes. First [create a C API](http://stackoverflow.com/q/2045774/205580) for your C++ classes. Once you have the C API working and tested, then work on creating the ctypes bindings.

Comment: ctypes not work with c++ classes - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1615813/how-to-use-c-classes-with-ctypes

Comment: As examples in these links show, don't forget about exception handling to avoid leaking C++ exceptions that should be handled as error codes. Note that if a Windows DLL is compiled with MSVC, C++ exceptions will use Windows exceptions. These will be caught by the ctypes structured exception handler, but that's not cross-platform and not very useful. Just catch and turn non-critical exceptions into error codes.

Comment: Okey guys, actually all what I wanted is to use the methods of this class, so I made a *.def file where I mentioned all the class methods (to avoid name mangling in c++). So now i'm able to call each method directly.

So to sum up, I cannot have a pointer to MyClass using ctypes even if I can call all the methods on it directly ?

Comment: A C++ instance method has an implicit `this` reference, but ctypes doesn't have a `thiscall` for calling instance methods in a 32-bit process.

Comment: Is there a way then to export classes in DLL and use them in Python without creating a C API ?

Comment: Not via ctypes, but you can use [Cython](http://docs.cython.org/src/userguide/wrapping_CPlusPlus.html) if compiling a Python extension module is acceptable.

Comment: Ok i'll see what I can do with Cython. Thanks a lot @eryksun.