# How to use python call a C++ dll which depends on other dll

Tags: python, c++, dll

Description:
I got two C++ classes named *bclass* and *nclass*. Both of two classes have made by .so already. My target is to use python to create a *nclass* and call a method named add in *nclass*. By the way, *nclass* depends on *bclass*. I plan to use ctypes module, but when a write the code `"lib=CDLL("./libnclass.so")"`

an error comes and show that

> "OSError: libbclass.so: cannot open shared object file:No such file or
> directory"

When I just call libbclass.so program is OK

So I got two questions,

**first,**

how do I call *nclass* in python,

**second**

how do I create an object by *nclass* and using some method in *nclass*

Comment: Please check this [post](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/30153/oserror-libportmidi-so-cannot-open-shared-object-file-no-such-file-or-directo) to get rid of this error ''OSError: libbclass.so: cannot open shared object file:No such file or directory".

Comment: Just to warn you, your code will not be portable across different c++ compilers. If you know the compiler of the so, then you can still use the library, you'll just have to figure out what name mangling convention it uses. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1615813/how-to-use-c-classes-with-ctypes