# Building a shared object from a single .cpp

Tags: python, c++, shared-libraries

I am trying to build a shared object library from a `cpp` file that is a simple set of functions.  I want to use `ctypes` to interface with python.

Say I have  the `cpp` file:

```
#include "print.h"
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>
#include <dlfcn.h>

void print_array(const std::vector<std::vector<float>> &A){
  for(size_t i = 0; i < A.size(); i++) {
    for(size_t j = 0; j < A[0].size(); j++) {
      std::cout << A[i][j] << "\n";
    }
  }
}
```

and header file

```
#ifndef ADD_H
#define ADD_H
#include <vector>

void print_array(const std::vector<std::vector<float>> &A);

#endif
```

I tried to build

```
g++ -fpic -c print.cpp -o print.o
g++ -shared -o print.so print.o
```

Then in python

```
from cytpes import cdll
print_lib = cdll.LoadLibrary("print.so")
```

the line

```
print_lib.print_array()
```

yields

```
AttributeError: ./print.so: undefined symbol: print_array
```

`nm -D print.so`

gives the output

```
0000000000201060 B __bss_start
                 U __cxa_atexit
                 w __cxa_finalize
0000000000201060 D _edata
0000000000201068 B _end
0000000000000c14 T _fini
                 w __gmon_start__
0000000000000898 T _init
                 w _ITM_deregisterTMCloneTable
                 w _ITM_registerTMCloneTable
                 w _Jv_RegisterClasses
0000000000000a50 T _Z11print_arrayRKSt6vectorIS_IfSaIfEESaIS1_EE
0000000000000bcc W _ZNKSt6vectorIfSaIfEE4sizeEv
0000000000000bf2 W _ZNKSt6vectorIfSaIfEEixEm
0000000000000b6a W _ZNKSt6vectorIS_IfSaIfEESaIS1_EE4sizeEv
0000000000000ba2 W _ZNKSt6vectorIS_IfSaIfEESaIS1_EEixEm
                 U _ZNSolsEf
                 U _ZNSt8ios_base4InitC1Ev
                 U _ZNSt8ios_base4InitD1Ev
                 U _ZSt4cout
                 U _ZStlsISt11char_traitsIcEERSt13basic_ostreamIcT_ES5_PKc
```

What am I fundamentally doing wrong in the compilation step?

Comment: Notice how it says, `undefined symbol: print_array`. It seems like the symbol in **print.so** is `_Z11print_arrayRKSt6vectorIS_IfSaIfEESaIS1_EE`

Comment: You have been hit by c++ ABI. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1615813/how-to-use-c-classes-with-ctypes

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are calling a C++ function while `ctypes` expects C functions linkage:

- C functions have a different (i. e. none) name mangling, as you noticed
- C function cannot have C++ parameters (std objects like std::vector, references, etc.)

To solve your issue, declare a clean C-style API in your headers, and if you intend to implement the functions in C++ and use g++ as your compiler/linker, you must add an `extern "C"` declaration right before the function declaration in the header file, or as a block around your declarations:

```
extern "C" void print_array(...);
```

This will prevent the C++ name mangling.

Using vectors and other C++ types in your interface functions will cause you ABI issues, i. e. "it won't work", even if everything links and compiles seemingly cleanly.

Use C functions with the data types supported by ctypes (see [Python docs on ctypes](https://docs.python.org/3/library/ctypes.html#fundamental-data-types)) in your functions as an interface, feel free to implement in C++, but then wrap your C function declarations in an `extern "C"` block to prevent name mangling.

Please do refer to the documentation of ctypes to find out how to *correctly* use structs, unions, references, etc. as function parameters, as there are many pitfalls and issues to consider.

Comment: agreed, I am going to stick with arrays since I do not need dynamic structures.

Comment: @mdoubez What are you talking about? It's absolutely fine to mark C++ functions as `extern "C"`. `extern "C"` tells the compiler not to perform name mangling on the function and instead emit a C-compatible symbol.

Comment: it also modifies the calling convention and "C" doesn't have a calling convention for the parameter std::vector<>&. You couldn't expose the same function to a C compiler.

Comment: Passing in a numpy array is passed as float *var.  I then convert to c++ types in an inner function.  This method worked well for me!