# Python wrapper for C++ class (when only ".h" and ".dll" files are available)

Tags: python, c++, dll, wrapper, ctypes

### Situation

I am trying to write a python wrapper for an already existing C++ application. The C++ source code of the application is not available to me. What I do have is a header file `zq_extapi.h` and a library file `zq_extapi.dll`. The file `zq_extapi.h` contains the following:

```cpp
#ifndef ZQ_EXTAPI_DECLS
#define ZQ_EXTAPI_DECLS
#endif

class ZQ_ExtAPI
{
protected:
    virtual ~ZQ_ExtAPI() {}

public:
    virtual const char* RunZQCommand(const char* str, int* res_code=(int*)0) = 0;

};

extern "C" ZQ_EXTAPI_DECLS
ZQ_ExtAPI* Open_ZQ_ExtAPI(int* err_code=0, int nargs=0, void** args=0);
```

### Tried thus far

I've tried to write a python wrapper using [`ctypes`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/ctypes.html):

```py
import ctypes
lib = ctypes.cdll.LoadLibrary("zq_extapi.dll")

class ZQ_ExtAPI(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.obj = lib.Open_ZQ_ExtAPI(ctypes.byref(err_code), 0)

    def RunZQCommand(self, command):
        # ??????

zq_ext_api_object = lib.Open_ZQ_ExtAPI(0, 0)
```

This code seems to be successful in initializing a C++ `ZQ_ExtAPI` object. Subsequently I'd like to execute the `RunZQCommand` of the created `ZQ_ExtAPI` object, but at this point I'm stuck.

### Question

If I understand correctly, then it's not possible to call the `RunZQCommand` C++ method directly from a python `ctypes` wrapper because the method has no C-linkage. What additional code would I need in order to make to make the `RunZQCommand` C++ method callable from a python `ctypes` wrapper?

*Note: if there's another easier way than `ctypes` to make a python wrapper for my C++ application, then I would be very interested in that as well.*

Comment: You can't call C++ code because of C++ ABI (name mangling and the way objects are laid out in memory); see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1615813/how-to-use-c-classes-with-ctypes). You'll need to do a `C` interface if you still want to use ctypes or use something [that can generate the glue for you](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/145270/calling-c-c-from-python).

Comment: Once you have that C API, I highly recommend looking into Cython. It makes it easy to write really Pythonic interfaces.